# How to merge zcat and bzcat in a single function

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, bzip2, fastq

I would like to build a little helper function that can deal with fastq.gz and fastq.bz2 files.

I want to merge zcat and bzcat into one transparent function which can be used on both sorts of files:

```
zbzcat example.fastq.gz
zbzcat example.fastq.bz2


zbzcat() {
  file=`echo $1 | `
## Not working
  ext=${file##*/};
  
  if [ ext == "fastq.gz" ]; then
    exec gzip -cd "$@"  
  else
    exec bzip -cd "$@"  
  fi
}
```

The extension extraction is not working correctly. Are you aware of other solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are quite a lot of problems:

- `` file=`echo $1 | ` ``  gives a syntax error because there is no command after `|`. But you don't need the command substitution anyways. Just use `file=$1`.
- `ext=${file##*/}` is not extracting the extension, but the filename. To extract the extension use `ext=${file##*.}`.
- In your check you didn't use the variable `$ext` but the literal string `ext`.
- Usually, only the string after the last dot in a filename is considered to be the extension. If you have `file.fastq.gz`, then the extension is `gz`. So use the check `$ext = gz`. That the uncompressed files are `fastq` files is irrelevant to the function anyways.
- `exec` replaces the shell process with the given command. So after executing your function, the shell would exit. Just execute the command.

By the way: You don't have to extract the extension at all, when using pattern matchting:

```
zbzcat() {
  file="$1"
  case "$file" in
    *.gz) gzip -cd "$@";;
    *.bz2) bzip -cd "$@";;
    *) echo "Unknown file format" >&2;;
  esac
}
```

Alternatively, use `7z x` which supports a lot of formats. Most distributions name the package `p7zip`.

Comment: I first tried it with $1 alone, but this does not work well with the suffix replacement. I updated my code. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This would work equally well as a one-liner wrapper utility `zbzcat(){ { zcat "$1"||bzcat "$1";}2>/dev/null;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
ext=${1##*.}
```

Why are you throwing in an `echo` and try to strip a `/`?

Also, the string `ext` (3 characters) will never be equal to the string `fastq.gz` (7 characters). If you want to check that the extension equals `gz`, just do a

```
if [[ $ext == gz ]]
```

Having said this, relying on the extension to get an idea of the content of a file is a bit brave. Perhaps a more reliable way would be to use the `file` to determine the most likely file type. The probably safest approach would be to just try a *bzip* extraction first, and if it fails, do the *gzip* extraction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The echo function I used because ${$1} did not work, but the double dollar is apparently not necessary. How would you test if a bzip extraction fails ?

Comment: Redirecting stderr to the bitbucket and checking the exit code. The bzip2 man-page says: _Return values: 0 for a normal exit, 1 for environmental  problems  (file not  found, invalid flags, I/O errors, &c), 2 to indicate a corrupt compressed file, 3 for an internal consistency error_

Comment: @PeterPisher : `${${something}}` does not make sense in bash, AFIK. In zsh, there are certain circumstances, where this kind of nesting works, but then you usually have flags involved, for instance `${(Q)${something}}`. Not sure what you wanted to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you would use mimetype.

File extensions are not always correct.

```sh
decomp() {  
  case $(file -b --mime-type  $1)  in
    "application/gzip")
         gzip -cd "$@"
         ;;
    "application/x-bzip2")
         bzcat  "$@"
         ;;
    "application/x-xz")
        xzcat "$@"
        ;;
    *) 
      echo "Unknown file format" >&2
    ;;
  esac
}
```